# Google Recaptcha slows page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recaptcha

I have a web page with 10 different forms. I rendered 10 different recaptchas using JavaScript. The problem is that when the page is loaded, it takes around 3-4 seconds to load and I don't like it. If I remove the `recaptha.js`, it loads in 1 second. Any ideas?

Comment: Might be some kind of internet problems or post your code.

Comment: Are all 10 visible to the user? If no, then you can delay the loading until each form is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some tests and the problem was rendering 10 captchas at the same time, for some reason it takes like 1 second each 4 recaptchas. I solved it by rendering each recaptcha when the form is loaded, so it's reseted each time I open a new form.